# Index and Match error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I keep getting a Ref error.

my formula is

```
=INDEX(H:H,MATCH(J2,A:A,0),MATCH(K1,E:E,0))
```

If I dont use the second match, it works but only pulls the first match of the employee # but I also want to match the date as well.

[image]

Comment: The third criterion of INDEX is the column Reference not a second row reference.

Comment: Check out my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another) for ideas on how to do a two item lookup.

Comment: Try to use SUMPRODUCT function.

Answer (score 0):

*After little modification the used formula works properly.*

[image]

- Formula in cell `F126`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(C126:C131,MATCH(E126,A126:A131,0),MATCH(F$124,B126:B131,0)),"")
  ```

**N.B**

- Match date (in your case in `K1`), must be either an absolute or mixed cell reference, `$k$1` or `k$1`, because as soon you drag formula down Row number increases like `K2` and so on, causes no value or may be wrong match if value available in downwards cell.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: This is only working because the second match is returning `1`, Change the date to `12/29/19` and it will not work as the second match will then return `2` and there are not two columns in your Index Range.

Comment: @ScottCraner, thanks for observation,,, the match date (mm/dd/yy) is with 3 rows only, where Ids  ends with 622, 057 & 431, (C126, C129 & C131) so that the formula returns related values from Pay Code, since formula works with 2 criteria. DATE & PAY CODE. I've changed date in F124 to 12/29/19 returns CAN Paid TO from C127. Please write if isn't working.